# Intuitive explaination for the influence of different mass-energy components on the CMB

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, mass-energy, cosmic-microwave-background, intuition

So I'm going to be giving a talk to a local astronomy club, and I want to be able to give them an intuitive understanding of why the CMB tells us about both the geometry of the universe and the matter content.

I think there is a reasonably good explanation for the geometry piece - in positively curved spacetimes, photon paths converge, which means spots in the CMB would be larger, the opposite in negatively curved universes. We are right about in the middle.

But I don't have as good an explanation for how the precise matter content (matter vs photons vs cosmological constant) modifies the CMB. I can say things like "matter scales like $R^{-3}$, radiation scales like $R^{-4}$, so the oscillation scale is different", but that doesn't seem very satisfactory to me. I'm sweeping a lot under the "it's a fit to a model" rug.

I guess my understanding would that in the radiation dominated universe, the typical scales of interactions are smaller, so that's where the smaller scale features in the CMB comes from (after quantum fluctuations, I suppose). The larger scale ones from matter, and dark energy creates oscillations which are independent of scale.

Anyone have a better intuitive explanation for this? Don't know it until you can explain it to a 3rd grader, right?

EDIT: To be clear, I am NOT talking about the concordance model - I don't want to use SN Ia, galaxy clustering, or anything else. WMAP fits say "here are the components", that's the argument I'm looking for.